# Fullcalendar.js, month view, get cell date while render for even/odd week number

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

Anybody knows how to get cell date while render event for descision to render or not event? 
IN MONTH VIEW.
I made it for "week view" but for month it turns into hell's kitchen.
I even tried to modificate fullcalendar script, but it seems meaningless.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    minTime: '08:00',
    //maxTime: '22:00',
    lang: 'ru',
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    editable: false,
    weekNumbers: true,
    allDayDefault: false,
    events:  events,
    eventRender: function(element, event, view){

         $(event).find('div.fc-title').html(element.title);
         $(event).find('span.fc-title').html(element.title);

        // Odd-Even
        switch (element.range) {
            case 'every week':
                var period = 'every';
                break;
            case 'even week':
                var period = 'even';
                break;
            case 'odd week':
                var period = 'odd';
                break;
            default:
                // statements_def
                break;
        }

        if (view.type == 'agendaWeek'){
            mydate = new Date(view.currentRange.start._d);
            var result = getWeekNumber(mydate);
            if (period == result) {
                return true;
            }else if (period == 'every'){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else if(view.type == 'month'){

            //don't know what to do, view start and end date - month start and end

        }
        // END Odd-Even
    }

});
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create repeating events with rules about frequency? I think there is a better way 
- Personally I would do it on the server side, using logic much more easily to generate the correct JSON event data, omitting the ones that shouldn't be shown from the feed entirely, rather than trying to prevent it rendering at the last moment by scrabbling around in the DOM for date information. Also it seems like your logic would break entirely if the event crosses more than one day? Then there would be no specific "date cell" to search for, there would be several.

Comment: @ADyson , it's a students schedule, lessons won't be lasting for several days. So, what correct JSON would you recommend if lesson repeats only on odd number of week of the year? Item with range property with array from 106 date ranges?

Comment: no, I would suggest to make 1 event for each actual occurence that you want to display. So for an event that repeats 1 day of the week, on odd numbered weeks, if there are 52 weeks in the year then there would be 26 events in the JSON for that lesson. In other words, implement the range logic on the server, not in fullCalendar. Then fullCalendar can just dumbly display whatever events it is given.

Comment: @ADyson, Anyways, I'll need to calculate ranges of odd weeks in date "from-to" and write it in event. It's stupid. So there's is not such functionality as dow for weeks. I'll try to search another calendar plugin.

Comment: well actually if you take my suggestion you don't need to find another calendar plugin. I don't actually know of any web-based ones which support what you need directly, but if you find one I'd be interested to know. I still think you're better implementing your range calculations on the server and using that to create separate event objects for rendering on the calendar.